# Apache a2enconf in a Docker container

Tags: php, apache, rest, mod-rewrite, docker

I'm trying to follow [this code](http://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/851_rest/code.zip) obtained in [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-http-and-rest--net-16340), without success.

On my local machine, I get it to work (**although I had to modify the rewrite rules**). But when trying to use a Docker container, I get error 404 when I try to access the example REST resources:

```
$docker-compose logs -f

web_1  | 172.27.0.1 - - [19/Jul/2017:17:45:58 +0000] "GET /clients/jim HTTP/1.1" 404 501 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
web_1  | 172.27.0.1 - - [19/Jul/2017:17:46:20 +0000] "GET /clients/anne HTTP/1.1" 404 502 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
```

It seems to me that the error happens with `a2enconf`, since it works if I use an `.htaccess` file and add the following line in`volumes`:

```
- "./code/rest.conf:/var/www/html/.htaccess:Z"
```

---

### Dockerfile

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite
COPY rest.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/
RUN a2enconf rest
```

### rest.conf

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ server.php
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: myphp:5.6-apache-rewrite
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - "./code/server.php:/var/www/html/server.php:Z"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

---

## Inside the container

```
# apache2ctl -t

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.27.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK

# apache2ctl -M
Loaded Modules:
(...)
 rewrite_module (shared)
(...)

# apache2ctl -S
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.27.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   172.27.0.2 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You lack `RewriteOptions InheritDown`:

```
  RewriteOptions InheritDown
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ server.php
```

Because the rest.conf is being placed outside the VirtualHost.

---

But I prefer to do this instead:

**rest.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ server.php
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite
COPY rest.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking the issue was with Docker and not Apache. With your explanation I got it working (although I couldn't get the first option to work, as apparently I need to have `RewriteEngine on` on every Virtual Host, even when `RewriteOptions InheritDown` is turned on)

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy, ok, glad to hear it!